# View changes from "git log -p" in "difftool"

Tags: git, workflow, meld, difftool

I'm getting branch changes for review by using `git log -p master..newbranch`, but it just gives me diff file. How can I view this diff with external tool like meld? I want to see what was changed only in this specific branch (from branch start to tip).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, I've found it's done like this:

```
git difftool --dir-diff master...newbranch
```