# Is the a shorter way of writing git diff HEAD^ HEAD?

Tags: git, git-diff

I find myself typing this pretty often, like when I made some change, committed it, and then either need to look up something I did there to figure out what to do next, or make sure I didn't add anything unintended to the commit before pushing it to a remote.

Admittedly, `diff HEAD^ HEAD` is fast enough to type (`git di`<kbd>TAB</kbd>`H`<kbd>TAB</kbd><kbd>←</kbd>`^ H`<kbd>TAB</kbd>), but it still feels like there should be a better way.

*How do I easiest see all changes made in the last commit?*

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Try [`git show`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-show). Without other options, it shows a diff of the latest commit.

`git show $something` shows the content of `$something` in a user-friendly way. When `$something` refers to a file, `git show` will display the file's content. When it refers to a commit, Git shows the commit (author, date, commit log and diff). `git show` without more arguments is equivalent to `git show HEAD`.

Comment: Brilliant! Could you also explain why `show` does this? I normally use that to display entire files at some revision; would never have though that it shows a diff when given no arguments.

Comment: @leftaroundabout `git show <commit_id>` will display the log message and the textual diff of the given commit. If not commit id is given, HEAD is used.

Answer (score 9):

I also found [in this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21640090/745903) that `@` is a shortcut for `HEAD`. So

```
git diff @^ @
```

or

```
git show @
```

is also an option.

Comment: Yep, @ is an alias to HEAD indeed.

Answer (score 5):

You can use one of the following:

**(Choose the one which suits you and make it an alias).**

```
# the equivalent command (dry run) for pull/push
git log ^branch1 branch2
git log branch1 ^branch 2
```

---

## ***`git show`***

```
# to view the content of the last commit
git show
```

> Shows one or more objects (blobs, trees, tags and commits).
>
> For commits it shows the **log message and textual diff**. 
>   It also presents the merge commit in a special format as produced by git diff-tree --cc.

---

## ***`git log --cc`***

From git v>2.6 you have the `--cc` flag added to the log so you can use

```
git log --cc
```

It will display the full log with the diff as well.

[image]

---

## ***`git diff-tree --cc HEAD`***

Very similar to the `git log --cc`. Behind the scenes `git show` is an alias to this command.

[image]

Comment: I'll probably use mostly the simple `git show`, but nice to know about `log --cc` too.  Could come handy when I need to know about the last _three_ commits or so.

Answer (score 0):

A pretty sweet way would be to use an alias. Sure, it's a quick fix but

```
$> alias gd="diff HEAD^ HEAD"
```

would do the trick. 
Now you can use:

```
$> gd
```

and your command would be run.

Add the `alias` command to your `~/.bashrc`, or likewise, and you don't have to write it in the beginning of each console session.

Answer (score 0):

Info: The shortest syntax using `git diff` seems like:

```
git diff @^!
```

i.e. `git diff HEAD^!`

Or use the shortest `git show` as mentioned.

For syntax meaning, see https://git-scm.com/docs/gitrevisions#_other_rev_parent_shorthand_notations for `r1^!`